# Correct pattern for a VIM autocommand?

Tags: vim

I have a windows directory (`U:\S`) that contains files that must not be 
changed. Their read-only bit cannot be set, so they must remain writeable.

As I have to look into some of the file's content rather regurarly with VIM, I want to make sure that I don't accidentally change the file's conent.

So, I put the following line into my `.vimrc` conifugration file:

```
autocmd InsertEnter u:/s/* call confirm("File should not be changed")
```

which *seemed* to work fine.

But then, I have also directory named `U:\supportTerminal` that contains files
that I *have to* change. When I edit a file within that directory, the file pattern `u:/s/*` for some reason matches and my warning pops up.

I tried playing around with some pattern, but I found none that only matches within u:\s but not within u:\supportTerminal

So, how could I go about what I want?

Comment: I've no idea why the pattern matches the second directory, but you might use `set readonly` (action: BufRead) instead of `call confirm(...)` according to your description.

Comment: I cannot do that, the files must remain writeable at *all times*. I'm also inclined to think that `set readonly` would equally be fired for editing files in u:\supportTerminal.

Comment: Oh, I see, `set readonly` doesn't actually set the file system read only bit, but an internal one. Ok, in that case, that would work if the pattern matched correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That makes for a bug, which you should report to `vim-dev at vim.org`. In linux I don't have this behaviour: it matches nicely.

As a temporary workaround,

```
:au BufRead u:/s/* set readonly
:au! BufRead u:/supportTerminal/*
```

should first make the general rule and then remove the one dir as an exception. Not sure whether this works in Windows GVim properly. Should this fail, other hack would be:

```
:au BufRead u:/supportTerminal/* set noreadonly
```

PS: As mentioned in the comments above, setting vim's own setting `readonly` works better to prevent accidental edits. User can't `:write` files with RO flag on, but it can be circumvented by setting `noreadonly` if needed.